# Can I use a script to restore multiple SQL databases from .bak files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore

I'm migrating 100 plus SQL databases over to a new server in a new location. I have the maintenance plan in place to take full back ups and then a script to copy over the `.bak` files to a temp directory. What I'm looking for is a way to mass restore those `.bak` files so that I don't have to spend all weekend doing it manually.

I found a decent stored procedure here : [SQL Restore](https://web.archive.org/web/20160113133807/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jenss/archive/2011/09/08/bulk-backup-and-restore-at-the-tip-of-your-finger.aspx)

I put it in place and tested and I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 3118, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The database "TF058" does not exist. RESTORE can only create a database when restoring either a full backup or a file backup of the primary file.
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I'm running SQL Server 2012 and the databases are in FULL recovery mode.

Comment: Take a peek at my answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72854/restore-all-databases-script/72857#72857

Answer (score 5):

You can use

1. sqlmigration - [Start-SqlServerMigration.ps1](https://github.com/ctrlbold/sqlmigration)

   > This script provides the ability to migrate databases using detach/copy/attach or backup/restore. SQL Server logins, including passwords, SID and database/server roles can also be migrated. In addition, job server objects can be migrated and server configuration settings can be exported or migrated. This script works with named instances, clusters and SQL Express.
2. Restore Genie - it has both [PowerShell](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/ps_restoregene/) and [t-SQL](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/sp_restoregene/) version.

I have used both and they are life savers. Highly recommend to test them first. First one is the one that will help in your situation.