# Restoring from a backup having dynamic file names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore

I want to restore a backup from a set of multiple files. The file names are generated dynamically. I have to restore the UAT with that backup. I need to schedule a job for this restore.

This is SQL Server 2012. Our backup script is split into 20 files, and everytime they are generated with timestamp. Now while restoring, we need the restore job to pick up those dynamic files from the backup location. Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72854/restore-all-databases-script